# Custom Template folder not being seen in TexWorks

Tags: texworks

I am using TexWorks and MiKTeX for my LaTeX editing. I want to add a custom template to TexWorks so I went to `TekWorks` > `templates`

and then created a new folder to put the `.tex` file into. I then restarted TexWorks and went to `File` > `New From Template`, but I do not see my new folder there.

Can anyone tell me what to do to remedy this?